# Сравнение каждого элемента массива с двумерным массивом

Tags: python, массивы

Есть Массив

```
a = [125, 202, 380, 250 , 90]
```

Есть еще второй массив

```
b = [[1, 0], [2, 100], [3, 200], [4, 300]]
```

Нужно сравнить каждый элемент массива "а" со вторым значением массив "b" и создать новый список из номеров элементов, которые максимально больше элемента из списка "a".

Например:

- 125 > 100 но 125 < 200, значит это "2" ( 100 < 125 < 200)
- 202 > 200 но 202 < 300, значит это "3" (125 < 202 < 300).

Таким образом, должно получится:

```
[2, 3, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: а если массив `a = [90, 110, 120]`, то как результат должен выглядеть?

Comment: ну если нужно сравнить, то выхода нет, придется сравнивать. Вот и сравнивайте.

Comment: ОЧЕНЬ БЛАГОДАРЕН ЗА ОТВЕТ!!! ВРОДЕ ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [125, 202, 380, 250 , 90]
b = [[1, 0], [2, 100], [3, 200], [4, 300]]
cash = []
for element_a in a:
    max_el = None # Задаете начальное значение
    max_ind = None
    for ind, el_lst_b in enumerate(b): # вытаскивает индекс и элемент (в вашем случае это будет список)
        element_b = el_lst_b[1]  # Тут распаковываете, НО! ЕСЛИ ЭЛЕМЕНТ СПИСКА b БУДЕТ ИМЕТЬ МЕНЬШЕ 2 ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ, ТО БУДЕТ ОШИБКА
        if element_a > element_b:  # Стандартный поиск максимального элемента
            if max_el is None:
                max_el = element_b
                max_ind = ind
            else:
                if element_a > max_el:
                    max_el = element_b
                    max_ind = ind
    cash.append(None if max_el is None else max_ind + 1) # Тут добавится None, если нет элемента меньше элемента, чем в списке A
print(cash)  # [2, 3, 4, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

@АлексейБелкин если бояться, что массив b содержит 1 или 0 элементов, можно добавить  простой контроль

```
a = [125, 202, 380, 250, 90]
b = [1, 0], [2, 100], [3, 200], [4, 300]

res = []
for z in a:
    if len(b) < 2:
        i = b[0][0] if b else 0
    else:
        for (i, x), (j, y) in zip(b[:-1], b[1:]):
            if x <= z < y:
                break
        else:
            i = j
    res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Comment: if len(b) < 2 - вы тут проверите длину кортежа b, а не длину элемента кортежа

Comment: именно это и проверяю - количество элементов в списке. Ведь в b может и один элемент быть

Comment: В таком случае протестируйте свой вариант на таком тесте: b = [1, 0], [100], [3, 200], [4, 300]

Comment: тут получил списиок из 300 300 300 300

Comment: тут получится: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @АлексейБелкин я все-таки предполагаю, что структура данных будет сохраняться. Оба наших варинта не будут работать при a=150

Comment: @splash58, ну я это в комментариях к коду указал, в каком месте работать не будет и по какой причине.

Answer (score 0):

вот такой способ тоже выдает нужный результат, попробуйте потестировать:

```
a = [125, 202, 380, 250 , 90]
b = [[1, 91], [2, 100], [3, 200], [4, 300]]  # первый элемент изменен

c = []
b2 = sorted(b,key=lambda x: x[1])
for i in a:
    c.append(l[-1][0] if (l:=list(filter(lambda y: y[1]<i, b2))) else None)

print(c)  # [2, 3, 4, 3, None] - None если элементы не найдены
```